# unset not deleting key in multidimensional array

Tags: array-unset

I have multidimensional array and wants to remove delivery location where ever it exists

```
   Array
     (
     [0] => Array
      (
        [amountReceived] => 1
        [deliveryLocation] => germany
      )

      [1] => Array
       (
        [amountReceived] => 2
        [deliveryLocation] => bulgaria
       )
     )
```

**PHP**

```
     foreach ($arr as $val) 
      {
        foreach($val as $k => $v)
        {
            if($k == 'deliveryLocation')
            {
                unset($arr[$k]);
            }
        }
      }

      return $arr;
```

problem is it's returning above array as it is without removing any key from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy and fast to understand way

```
$t=0;
foreach ($arr as $val)
{
      unset($arr[$temp]['deliveryLocation']);
      $t++;
}
```